# Magnitude of elements of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{M} = [\mathbf{m}_1,\dots,\mathbf{m}_D]$, that is $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{M}^T$ = $\mathbf{I}$, we have $\forall j, \mathbf{m}_j^T\mathbf{m}_j = 1$. I have seen in a paper stated that: $1 = \mathbf{m}_j^T\mathbf{m}_j = \sum_{i=1}^{D}m_{ij}^2 \Rightarrow m_{ij}^2 \leq 1 \Rightarrow |m_{ij}| \leq 1$. Someone may think of it intuitively, but how can we prove it analytically?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your matrices square? If so then we have if you define orthogonal to be $M M^T = I$ this is equivalent to saying that the rows of your matrix form an orthonormal system. Then we have for each row $m_j$, that the norm $\| m_j \| = 1$. Since the norm is the squares of the coordinates, we have each coordinate is between 0 and 1.

This arguement shows the orthogonal group is bounded.

Comment: Are you sure about that claim? I don’t see how $\mathbf m_j^T\mathbf m_j=\sum_{j=1}^Dm_{jj}^2$. If instead you had $\dots=\sum_{j=1}^D m_j^2\implies m_j^2\le1\implies|m_j|\le1$, that would make sense to me. With that change, you also have your proof.

Comment: @NickR yes it is orthogonal, thanks for the point.

Comment: @amd i have corrected my question, now I think I got a geometrically intuitive explanation. Because, $||\mathbf{m}_j||^2=1$, they lie on circle, thus for each component we have $m_{ij}\in[-1,1] \iff |m_{ij}|\leq 1$.